# Code organization using several git repositories with a QT project

Tags: git, qt, git-submodules, organization, repository

I am looking for a way to structure a project that is mainly built around a Qt application on Linux system. what I need is the following:

- Project

  - .git
  - QT_Application

    - .git
    - src
    - resources
    - bla
  - Drivers

    - .git
    - src
    - libs
  - Utils

    - .git
    - src
    - libs

the Qt application will relatively access all other repositories like ../Utils/libs/xyz. does it make sense to separate it into git submodules and the root folder will be a git repo as well?

How would you realize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a main Git repository with Git repositories under it, you HAVE to use submodules. There is no other way to do it.

Comment: I know but Do I need to do it that way by using submodules? Or are there any other approaches when it comes to this kind of scenario?

Comment: You have to do it that way using submodules. There are no other approaches that Git is capable of using.